# Is there any way to lock on to watchtowers?

Tags: rage

While driving across the wasteland, it is not uncommon to run across a bandit watchtower:

[image: Watchtower]

These are not terribly dangerous while driving (their machine gun doesn't do an awful lot of damage, and they don't chase you, obviously) and there are certainly quite a few ways to get rid of them (ramming them, or stepping out of your vehicle and using a sniper rifle on the operator).

The thing is, I've never managed to get a lock on them to properly take them down with vehicle mounted weapons. Firing blindly at them will work, but some are placed in such a way as to make that nearly impossible. Is there some way to do this that I am missing, or is it impossible to get a lock on them?

Comment: Nice question, I tried many time to destroy them using car missiles with no luck.

Comment: I simply jump out, pull out my sniper riffle and blow their heads off. However, this can be difficult when you also have to fend off multiple bandits

Comment: THIS. Is relevant to my intrest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the lock on in the vehicles are only for vehicle to vehicle combat. You will have to ram them, hit the with the rocket launcher or snipe the gunner.

Comment: A burst with the machineguns is also pretty effective.